# How do I deploy my 3 tier wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am new to deploying WCF projects so I would appreciate a little guidance on deploying the project.

I have a VS2010 project that is using .NET 4 for the WCF service.

The WCF service accesses another project that I call the Data Access Layer (DAL). The WCF service simply passes the Request XML on to the DAL.

The DAL accesses a 3rd project that I use to communicate with SQL Server, dbConnection. dbConnection packages the information into a call to a stored procedure to be sent to a SQL Server. See the diagram below for a simple view.

[image]

So my first question is, how do I deploy the Data Access assembly. I was thinking I put the assembly on its own server and then register it on that box. And I would have a reference to the assembly's path in my WCF project.

My 2nd question is, do I deploy the dbConnection assembly the same way? Do I register it and the Data Access assembly has a reference to its path?

Comment: Does the WCF service have a reference to the two DB related Dlls? If so, they might as well be on the same machine as the WCF service-- they will be loaded into memory. You might be able do so some trick to locate the bin folder from a shared drive, but I'd be surprised if that worked. Alternatively you might be saying you have a WCF serice that talks to a WCF service, maybe over a different protocol.

Comment: The WCF service references the Data Access project only. The Data Access project references the dbConnection project. These are separate projects in Visual Studio but I need to know how to physically place the files on separate servers and talk to one another.

Comment: They have to be on the same machine. The only way your graph is coherent with two servers is if there is yet another WCF service on the DB server, but I'm not sure what value that would add.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand. My requirements are that the WCF service be in the DMZ and have no logic (basically just pass the request info to the DAL). Is it OK to have everything in the DMZ?

Comment: Yes, malicious code that can call your WCF services, still can't call other methods in a dll *unless* such malicious code is uploaded to your server and executed. Also, if you hypothetically could put those dlls on another machine, the WCF server would have to have the *same* level of access as if those DLLs were on the same machine.

What you are passing to the DAL is SQL. You data access library sends SQL to the DB and gets back tables. You aren't sending C# requests to SQL.

Comment: Thanks  @MatthewMartin. You have put me on the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You decompose tiers wrong. If you think about 3 tier there will be:

1 - client pc that call your wcf service
2 - WCF service with its dataaccess layer
3 - SQl database.

[image]

If you want to speak about layered application, it is about application with n layers but this layers can be in one process.

Comment: I gave you an upvote and marked your answer, because you said the same thing as @MatthewMartin.